# workflow for website skinning using git and capistrano and cakephp

Tags: git, cakephp, capistrano

There is two parts to this question. The first is, I want to do a strawpoll off a worflow i've come up with, for code versioning a large number of websites. I have a master containing a cookie cutter website, and a series of branches that are handling changes to the views and config folder of each website. The models and controllers are the same for each site. If I make a change to the master, is it possible to merge those changes into each branch. It sounds ass backwards to me. I plan to use capistrano to deploy the sites, and may come up with a script that runs through each site, and merges the master into the branch, im not sure. Each site will have its own deploy scripts and point to a specific branch or site. I haven't got into the finer points of the deploy scripts yet, though before I start I want to see if my workflow is doable. Also, if the above is fine, if I tweak the controllers on one branch, I'm wondering if there will be merge nightmares.

If anyone else has a different approach, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Clarification question: It sounds like you have 3 (or some number) websites which all start from the same original template. And that each website has its own branch, and that the original template has its own branch. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read about the [git branch philosophy](http://gitster.livejournal.com/42247.html) written directly by the maintainer of git.

That sounds like a fine idea to me. From my understanding, if the purpose of branch `site-1` is "the website for customer 1, exactly how customer 1 wants it", then if customer 1 wants/needs the changes you made to branch `site-template`, then it is fine by 'git philosophy' to make a script that can push those changes to all the individual sites.